# Matlab fill matrix with certain value between two lines (Bresenham)

Tags: matlab, matrix, fill, bresenham, ert

For a school project we need to determine any sort of damage on a carbon fiber sheet with eight metal pins. To determine the damage we use resistivity measurements between multiple points.

We us a Matlab script to make the resistance between points visible. We plot the values in a matrix and create a line with the Bresenham function.

```
for x = 1:8
S1_(x) = 0;
end
p1 = [150 1];                                   
p2 = [(150+150*sind(45)) (150-150*cosd(45))];
p3 = [300 150]; 
m1 = zeros(300);
m2 = zeros(300);
[x1_1,y1_1] = bresenham(p1(1),p1(2),p2(1),p2(2));
m1(sub2ind(size(m1), y1_1, x1_1)) = S1_(1);
[x1_1,y1_2] = bresenham(p1(1),p1(2),p3(1),p3(2));
m2(sub2ind(size(m2), y1_2, x1_1)) = S1_(2);
mP1=m1+m2;
```

The problem is as follows:

The Bresenham function does create the lines in the matrix, but we are searching for a function too fill the matrix between two lines with the average of those two lines combined. The average of `S1_(1)` and `S1_(2)` need to fill the matrix between line `x1_1,y1_1` and `x1_1,y1_2`. The final plot is where all the points are drawn, when all areas between the lines are filled this should create a high top somewhere in the circle:

[image: Final plot]

Could someone help me solving this problem?

**UPDATE:**

We finally got it working, we call a function to create a triangular matrix and add up all those matrices.

[image: Correct plot]

Comment: if you want a single colour per 'face' you can use `imfill`. If the value is meant to vary according to the distance from the line, then you have no choice but to calculate this point by point. (there might be a creative way to use `bwdist` for this, but I can't think of an easy one at a glance).

Comment: Alternatively collect all triangles (maybe using a `delaunay` triangulation) and plot with `trisurf`

Comment: Why not draw a line between points? 'help line'

Comment: @LeonardoHermoso If I use the line function line(x,y,z) my resistance needs to be the same length as the x and y values, but since the array length depends on the pin position on the carbon fibre sheet, the length varies with the position.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thank you for your input, perhaps we do misunderstand each other, but it is not about changing the colour of a triangle.

I've created a simple scenario in Paint (so sorry for the painting skills)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIS5k.png

Comment: Yes, I'm confused what you're trying to do. Perhaps because you use terminology in confusing contexts. What does it mean to "fill a matrix between two lines?", or "the average of two lines"?. If by matrix you mean the domain of points in the image (e.g. pixels),  and by lines you mean "all the points *on* a line have a particular value, therefore I would like a point situated *between* two lines to have a value equal to the mean of those two values", then fine, but you still don't explain which two lines, given there will be triangular and rectangular shapes arising from the intersections.